# Как посчитать чернослив?

Tags: множественное-число

Как правильно: *четыре чернослива* или *четыре штуки чернослива?*

Comment: Четыре чернослива тоже корректно. Если речь идет о кустах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ЧЕРНОСЛИВ, -а (-у); м. собир. Сушёные плоды сливы сортов Венгерки.
> Сладкий ч. Компот из чернослива. Тушить баранину с черносливом.
> <Черносливовый; Черносливный, -ая, -ое. Черносливная наливка.
> Черносливовый соус, компот. Черносливные косточки. Черносливовые глаза
> (трад.-поэт.; о жгуче чёрных, влажных глазах).

Поскольку это слово собирательное, с числительными его следует употреблять опосредованно: пять ягод чернослива, четыре ягоды чернослива.

Comment: Спасибо! Ягоды подойдут

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: ***пять черносливин, четыре черносливины…***

> **ЧЕРНОСЛИВИНА**, -ы; ж. Разг. Отдельная ягода чернослива
>
> [http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=черносливина](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)